# IE9 Bug? <script> content executed twice when using Node.cloneNode(true)

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I know IE9 is kind of old now, but it is the lowest version of IE that I still must support in a Web application I'm building.

Anyway, while doing some DOM manipulation and testing in different browsers, I noticed that IE9 was doing something ***very*** strange. I had a <script> block in a DIV element, and when I deep-cloned that DIV element using Node.cloneNode(true), and attached the clone to the document somewhere using document.body.appendChild or document.body.insertBefore, the cloned <script> block would get executed again! No other browser exhibits this behavior.

If I'm not mistaken, <script> blocks aren't supposed to be executed when appended to the document after the document has initially loaded, am I right? If I'm correct, is this a bug in IE9?

Here is a simple HTML document where you can see this behavior in action. Create an HTML document with this code and load it up in Internet Explorer using IE9 emulation. You should see an alert popup that says "hey". Next, click the "Click Me" button, and you will see the same popup get executed again!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>IE9 Script Tag Bug Test</title>
<script>
function ButtonClick(){
var Elem = document.getElementById('mydiv');
var ElemClone = Elem.cloneNode(true);
document.body.insertBefore(ElemClone,Elem);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mydiv">
This is a DIV.
<script>
alert("hey");
</script>
</div>
<button onclick="ButtonClick();">Click Me</button>
</body>
</html>
```